# Finding an asymptotic solution for a first order ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, asymptotics

Given strictly concave function $f(t)$ that satisfies $f'(t)>0$, $f'(t)=o(1)$ (i.e. $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}f'(t)=0$) , and $f'(t)=\omega\left(t^{-1}\right)$ (i.e. $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}tf'(t)=\infty$) , we denote $F=\exp\left(f\left(t\right)\right)$. Let $H(t)$ be a solution of
$$ \dot{H}=F $$
Can we approximate H by F?

Specifically, I want to show that
$$ \lim_{s\to\infty}\frac{H^{-1}(s)}{F^{-1}(s)}=1\,, \ \ \ \ (a) $$
where $F^{-1}$ and $H^{-1}$ are the inverse functions of $F$ and $H$, respectively.

If necessary I can add additional assumptions on $f(t)$, though I would like to keep it as general as possible.

* In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309288/asymptotic-solution-for-a-first-order-ode) question, $(a)$ was proved for $f'(t)=\Omega(1)$ (without the assumption that $f(t)$ is strictly concave). I'm interested in the case that $f'(t)=o(1)$.

Comment: By $\dot{H}$ you mean the derivative of $H$, or something else ?

Comment: Yes, the derivative of $H$.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but a hint at a **negative** answer: take $f(t)=\log t$, which doesn't satisfy $\lim_{t\to\infty}tf'(t)=\infty$, critically, but is nearer to the proven case (where $f'(t)=\omega(1)$ ).

In this case you have $F(t)=t$, $H(t)=t^2/2$, $F^{-1}(s)=s$, $H^{-1}(s)=\sqrt{2s}$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I agree that eq. (a) doesn't hold for $f(t)=\log(t)$ which doesn't satisfy the condition $f'(t)=\omega(t^{-1})$. However, I think that with this condition the equation should be true. We have that $\dot{H}(t)=F(t)=\exp(f(t))$. If $\exp(f(t))\approx\exp(f(t))f'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\exp(f(t))$ then I think we can approximate $H\approx \exp(f) = F$. For this to hold we need $\log(f’(t))=o (f (t))$ (i.e. $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\frac{\log(f’(t))}{f(t)}=0$). Note that $f(t)=\log(t)$ doesn’t satisfy this requirement, but $f(t)=\log^\epsilon(t)$ for $\epsilon>1$ does.

Comment: Yes, it's more subtle than I thought...